# Separating aspects of dynamic web system

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, web

I'm revising for an exam and came across a past exam question that I am unsure of how to interpret:

"How to separate the various aspects of a dynamic web system (i.e. content, behaviour, presentation and data processing) when using PHP?"

The way I interpret this is that by content it is meant HTML, behaviour JavaScript, presentation CSS and data processing PHP, and that separating these aspects means separate files linked together for easier management, debugging and alterations.

Would that be a fair interpretation or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Consider reading about the Model-View-Controller (MVC) development pattern which separates data, logic, and presentation.

Comment: what you want is [MVC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc), where presentation is HTML+CSS (possibly some JS), behavior or "logic" is PHP and content is the database

Comment: Typically, when I think of separating the various aspects of a dynamic web system, I think of multi-tier: content being in a database, data processing being in a business logic layer (PHP), and presentation being in a web browser... but that does not seem to be a well worded question.

Comment: Sounds right. Separate the files. MVC might be a little over the top for this particular problem considering the php side could be just a few variables defined and spit out somewhere in the included html file. I assume this is a pretty low level assignment

Comment: Ask your professor or classmates who will know better than we will.